# Find words containing special characters with PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

I have a sentence include some wrong word (wrong word includes more than 1 special char: `== >> << ?? .. ,, !! ## $$ %% // ** -- ++  ex`...

I use `preg_match_all()` to count but the result is wrong.
Can you help me to fix it

```
str = "you he==rt are  my heart 4++5=9 9-8===1"
$pattern = '/[^\s]*(?:[\+]{2,}|[\%]{2,}|[\-]{2,}|[=]{2,}|[<]{2,}|[>]{2,}|[\*]{2,}|[\/]{2,}|[\:]{2,}|[\.]{2,}|[\?]{2,})/';
```

Result

```
he==
4++
8===
```

i need to find what the result is

```
he==rt
4++5=9
9-8===1
```

Thank you!

Comment: And what code have yoiu tried so far, so that we can support you finding issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?=(?:\S*[^\w\s]){2,})\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tL9pF8/2)

Details:

- `(?=(?:\S*[^\w\s]){2,})` - a positive lookahead that checks if, after the current location, there are 2 or more sequences of:

  - `\S*` - 0+ non-whitespace characters  followed with
  - `[^\w\s]` - a character other than a word or whitespace
- `\S+` - matches 1+ non-whitespace characters

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Z3SjXu):

```
$re = '~(?=(?:\S*[^\w\s]){2,})\S+~'; 
$str = "you he==rt are my heart 4++5=9 9-8===1 hyphenated-word"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]); // Array( [0] => he==rt [1] => 4++5=9  [2] => 9-8===1 )
```

Comment: What about for words with only one special character? It should match only for words with more than 1 special char, from my understanding of the OP.

Comment: Well, it is not a problem, just add a quantified group. [`(?=(?:\S*[^\w\s]){2,})\S+`](https://regex101.com/r/tL9pF8/3). Actually, this also depends on what context these should appear in. Thus, [`\b(?:\S*[^\w\s]){2}\S*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/tL9pF8/4)  can also be valid (if the special characters should only be inside word characters.